# Backbone.js + Relational + AMD ... bootstrapping relationals

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, commonjs, backbone-relational

I feel sort of lost and overlooking something, but i am not sure how to approach to this and even not very much sure how to ask...

First of all, i am using AMD approach (with curl.js library), which makes this probably more difficult, but i am not giving up on AMD because of this problem.

I have this structure of bootstrap data from the server, stored in '**window.bootstrap**' property.

```
Departments = [
  {"Id": 1, "Name": "Early Collections" },
  {"Id": 2, "Name": "Collections" }
]
Blocks = [
  {"Id": 1, "Code": "K", "Department": 1 },
  {"Id": 2, "Code": "A", "Department": 2 }
]
```

Now i am confused about approach to this. Here is my '**DataModel/Block**' module:

```
define [
    'Collection/DepartmentCollection'
    'DataModel/Department'
], (DepartmentCollection, Department) ->

    Backbone.RelationalModel.extend
        relations: [
            type: Backbone.HasOne
            key: 'Department'
            relatedModel: Department
            collectionType: DepartmentCollection
        ]
```

Module '**DataModel/Department**' is just plain RelationalModel without any relations. Also every mentioned Collection here is also plain without anything but reference to Model like this:

```
define ['DataModel/Department'] , (Department) ->
    Backbone.Collection.extend
        model: Department
```

And finally, here goes Bootstrap module, which looks like this:

```
define [
    'DataModel/Department'
    'Collection/DepartmentCollection'
    'DataModel/Block'
    'Collection/BlockCollection'
] , (Department, DepartmentCollection, Block, BlockCollection) ->

    model = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend
        relations: [
            type: Backbone.HasMany
            key: 'Departments'
            relatedModel: Department
            collectionType: DepartmentCollection
        ,
            type: Backbone.HasMany
            key: 'Blocks'
            relatedModel: Block
            collectionType: BlockCollection
        ]

    data = window.bootstrap || {}

    boot = new model
    boot.get('Departments').reset data.Departments || []
    boot.get('Blocks').reset data.Blocks || []

    return boot
```

I would expect from this, that it would find Departments for those Blocks and assign models there, but calling

```
console.debug ins.get('Blocks').at(0).get('Department')
```

...gets me undefined.

But this is not the end. I will be having other entities from server with relation to Department too. And i would like to see, it automatically attaches Department from that bootstrap, so i can use it transparently.

I don't know if i had just misunderstood this relational library, or it's not AMD ready. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I really don't have a clue what you mean by "AMD ready"? So it's pretty possible backbone-relational is not. I assume it's got nothing to do with your processor brand though ;).

Comment: Read on [CommonJS proposal](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition). Anyway, looks you have it AMD ready, it was just my error. Sorry for bothering you :) And thank you for this great library of yours. Saves a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks it's solved. Problem was in one line of code...

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute = "Id"
```

I forgot i am using PascalCase identifiers for object properties. Everything looks ok for now.

Answer (score 0):

Potential scoping / name resolution problem? What output do you get for `console.debug(window.Block, window.Department)`? If you do get the model type, it might help to give the `relatedModel` as a string, e.g. `relatedModel: "Department"`.

Comment: Well, how could i use string for relatedModel, when no object like "Department" is not in global context ? That's the purpose of AMD, not to clutter global context with object which has purpose only for some segments of application.